# Why chain rule isn't working here?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $(x,y,z)$ and $(x',y',z')$ be two points in space. Let the distance between them be $r$. Also let:

$x-x'=\xi$

$y-y'=\eta$

$z-z'=\zeta$

> Since $(x,y,z)$ and $(x',y',z')$ are two separate points, changing only the point $(x,y,z)$ will not change the point $(x',y',z')$. Therefore:
>
> $\dfrac{\partial x'}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial x'}=0$

Then:

$\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\dfrac{dr}{dr^2}\dfrac{\partial r^2}{\partial x}=\dfrac{1}{2r}\dfrac{\partial(\xi^2 +\eta^2 +\zeta^2)}{\partial \xi}\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}=\dfrac{1}{2r}.2 \xi.\dfrac{\partial(x-x')}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\xi}{r}$

and

$\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x'}=\dfrac{dr}{dr^2}\dfrac{\partial r^2}{\partial x'}=\dfrac{1}{2r}\dfrac{\partial(\xi^2 +\eta^2 +\zeta^2)}{\partial \xi}\dfrac{\partial \xi}{\partial x'}=\dfrac{1}{2r}.2 \xi.\dfrac{\partial(x-x')}{\partial x'}=-\dfrac{\xi}{r}$

Now let's find $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x'}$ by another way using **chain rule**:

$\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x'}=\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial x'}=\dfrac{\xi}{r}.0=0$

I guess I am getting different answers because there is something wrong in the application of chain rule here. Can someone explain why am I getting different answers?

Comment: $\partial$ doesn't satisfy the chain rule that $\mathrm{d}$ does.

Comment: You can't take the partial derivative on $x'$ while keeping $x'$ constant.

Comment: By using the chain rule in the last step you're implying that $x=x(x')$, otherwise this will not make sense. Using you're logic we could define the function $y=x+c$ ,where $c$ is constant and then saying $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial c} \frac{\partial c}{\partial x}=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you have to bear in mind about partial derivatives is they assume something is held constant, but $\partial_u v\partial_v w = \partial_u w$ is only guaranteed when the partial derivatives on the left-hand side hold the *same* things constant. Define $\alpha:=\left(\xi,\,\eta,\,\zeta\right)$. In your first calculation, you show $(\partial_{x'}x)_{\alpha}=0$, where the subscript indicates what's held constant. But in your final calculation, you try $(\partial_{x'}r)_{?}=(\partial_x r)_{x'}(\partial_{x'}x)_\alpha$, about which nothing follows from the chain rule.

Comment: Could you strictly explain what $(\partial_{x'} x)_{\alpha}$ is, given that $x$ and $x'$ are assumed to be coordinates of some points and no function or relation between them has been defined?

Comment: Since $x=x'+\xi$, that derivative is $1$.

Comment: @J.G.- I had a bit trouble understanding your derivative notation.... Thanks anyway

Comment: Formally, to even begin speaking of differentiation and the chain rule, we must define one or more functions (and obviously, it must be made absolutely clear which thing is a function and which is a variable). But here we have as much as a collection of indeterminates ($x$, $\xi$, $r$, etc.) and some relations between them, e.g. $\xi = x - x'$. No distinction between functions and variables is made, yet we proceed to differentiate those indeterminates one with respect to another in every possible way. (cont'd)

Comment: Even if the original relation $\xi = x - x'$ slightly suggests that $\xi$ is a function of variables $x$ and $x'$, it is freely transformed into $x = x' + \xi$, which supposedly justifies treating $x$ as a function of $x'$ and $\xi$ and differentiating it. It feels very alarming and unclear. That's why if you could explain in possibly strict terms some rigorous theory behind such seemingly incorrect operations, I think it would be very useful to many people here (including myself).

Comment: There's no variable-function distinction in multivariate calculus. Taking any formula relating quantities, you can take a partial derivative with respect to anything as long as you hold other things constant. It's just that *which* things you hold constant matters, and must be the same for every derivative when you use the chain rule. If you want to get a feel for this, work out all the partial derivatives, with all possible choices of what's held constant, when relating the $2$D Cartesian $x,\,y$ to $r, \,\theta$.

Comment: What is the meaning of a partial derivative then? Example: differentiating the formula $x = x' + \xi$ with respect to $\xi$ while holding everything else constant gives $\partial_{\xi} x = 1$. But what is the definition of $\partial_{\xi} x$ if we do not treat $x$ as a function of $\xi$?

Comment: That's not how it works. You treat $x$ as a function of whatever it's written in terms of, then decide what to hold constant. For example, you could hold $x'$ constant, or $x'-\xi$ if you really wanted to.

Comment: In the previous comment you wrote that there is no variable-function distinction in multivariate calculus (which was, I assume, a response to me saying that in order to differentiate anything, we must have defined a function of specific variables). Then you write that I should treat $x$ as a function of other variables occuring in the same formula (again, I assume it's for the purpose of differentiating it). Isn't that a contradiction?

Comment: @Adayah No, it isn't. What I'm saying is to differentiate $x$ you regard all symbols as variables, functions, call them what you will; they're all "on the same footing". We have $x=x'+\xi=x''+2\xi$, with $x'':=x'-\xi$. You can thus differentiate $x$ with respect to $\xi$, holding $x'$ constant to get an answer of $1$ or $x''$ constant to get an answer of $2$. Obviously, you could get any answer you like with the right what-is-constant convention. What's important is that, if you use the chain rule, every partial derivative you work with have the same convention.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written in the yellow box is nonsense.

An expression like $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}$ only makes sense when $x'$ is thought of as one of several independent variables, including presumably $y'$ and $z'$, when $x$ is as a function of all three of them (in that setting, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}$ is defined by holding $y'$ and $z'$ constant while letting $x'$ vary, and taking the limit of a very carefully formulated difference quotient).

Similarly, and expression like $\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}$ only makes sense when $x$ is thought of as one of several independent variables, including presumably $y$ and $x$, and when $x'$ is as a function of all three of them.

Obviously these two situations are incompatible, so any kind of relation or equation between $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}$ and $\frac{\partial x'}{\partial x}$ makes no sense, and any assumption of an equation like $\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} = 0$ makes no sense.